# Fragment'ы и переходы с использованием BottomNavigationView

Tags: java, android, bottom-navigation-view

Есть Activity с BottomNavigationView, который имеет в 3 фрагмента A, B и C. На фрагменте A есть кнопка, на которую назначил действие. Т.е я заменяю страницу в АФрагменте на Гфрагмент(и установил backgroundColor = #fff, чтобы не видеть А). Подскажите как правильно реализовать переходы между фрагментами, когда используется BottomNavigationView?

```
Button btn = getView().findViewById(R.id.Btn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                NotificationsFragment nextFrag= new NotificationsFragment();
                getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.frame_G, nextFrag, "1")
                        .addToBackStack(null)
                        .commit();
            }
        });
```

Вот AFragment.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".AFragment"
    android:id="@+id/frame_kek">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, у вас три фрагмента(А, Б, В), между которыми вы переключаетесь с помощью `BottomNavigationView`. При этом содержимое фрагмента А может быть в разных состояниях.

В таком случае я бы рекомендовал использовать фрагмент А как контейнер, его текущее содержимое сделать фрагментом Г, его альтернативное состояние - фрагментом Д. Во фрагменте А вызываете `childFragmentManager` и через него добавляете фрагмент Г во фрагмент А. Соответственно, при клике по кнопке, которая теперь находится на фрагменте Г, вызываем в А замену Г на Д. Таким образом вы можете сохранить состояние фрагмента А при переходе на фрагмент Б или В с помощью нижней панели, если А был в альтернативном состоянии, то при переходе на Б и возвращении на А он останется в альтернативном состоянии

Примерно так. Про setRetainInstance почитайте отдельно, если не знаете что это

```
public final class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {
    private final MyFragment[] fragments =
            new MyFragment[]{new A(), new B(), new C()};
    private int current;

    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.main, fragments[current]).commit();
    }

    public final void onBotNavViewClick(int index) {
        if (current != index && index >= 0 && index <= 2) {
            current = index;
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                       .replace(R.id.main, fragments[current]).commit();
        }
    }
}

public abstract class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    protected int layout_id;

    public MyFragment() {
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    @Nullable
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(layout_id, container, false);
    }
}

public final class A extends MyFragment, View.OnClickListener {
    private final D d = new D();
    private final E e = new E();
    private MyFragment current = d;

    {
        layout_id = R.layout.a;
        d.setListener(this);
        e.setListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        if (!current.isAdded()) {
            getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.de_container, current).commit();
        }

    }

    public final void omClick(View v) {
        if (current.equals(d)) {
            current = e;
        } else {
            current = d;
        }
        getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.de_container, current).commit();
    }
}

public final class B extends MyFragment {
    {
        layout_id = R.layout.b;
    }
}

public final class C extends MyFragment {
    {
        layout_id = R.layout.c;
    }
}

public class D extends MyFragment {
    {
        layout_id = R.layout.d;
    }
    private View.OnClickListener listener = null
    public void setListener(View.OnClickListener listener){
        this.listener = listener;
        if(button!=null)
            button.setOnClickListener(listener);
    }
    private Button button = null
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         button = view.findViewById(R.id.button);
         button.setOnClickListener(listener);
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        button = null;
    }
}

public final class E extends MyFragment {
    {
        layout_id = R.layout.e;
    }
    private View.OnClickListener listener = null
    public void setListener(View.OnClickListener listener){
        this.listener = listener;
        if(button!=null)
            button.setOnClickListener(listener);
    }
    private Button button = null
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         button = view.findViewById(R.id.button);
         button.setOnClickListener(listener);
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        button = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Если Вам не сложно могли бы реализовать это? А то я уже месяц ломаю голову над этим((